# Where should a question mark be placed in a short citation?

Tags: citations, grammar

According to [Modern Language Association (MLA) norms](http://www.mlahandbook.org/fragment/public_index) we should use punctuation marks after the page number, within parentheses, that follows the closing quotation mark. For example:

> According to Foulkes's study, dreams may express "profound aspects of
>   personality" (184).

But what if a question mark is inherent to the quotation? Example:

> “[t]o what extent do translation theorists engage with the experience
>   of translators and how are their theories shaped by what happens in
>   practice?” (16)

How should this be cited? Possibilities I can see:

> “[t]o what extent do translation theorists engage with the experience
>   of translators and how are their theories shaped by what happens in
>   practice” (16)?

Or

> “[t]o what extent do translation theorists engage with the experience
>   of translators and how are their theories shaped by what happens in
>   practice?” (16).

Which one is correct?

Comment: If your question mark belongs to the citation it should remain within the citation so your last example should be correct. Otherwise you are changing the quote you are referencing.

Comment: @PeterJansson And the closing parenthesis should still be followed by a dot?

Comment: That should be clear from the citation rules in the journal (equivalent) where the text should appear, so it may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Peter indicates, the question mark should remain with the original quotation, since it's in the original source material. Therefore, your second example is clearly incorrect. In addition, you *still* need the period following the citation, to indicate that you are ending the sentence in question. Therefore, you should use the last example.

However, I would also note that, as written, it looks like your example would also require the name of the author along with the parenthetical reference, so it would be more like:

> “[t]o what extent do translation theorists engage ith the experience of translators and how are their theories shaped by what happens in practice?” (Smith 16).

Comment: Thank you. The author has been mentioned earlier in the sentence, but I left it out to make my example as compact as possible.